# background-image in HTML, CSS and JavaScript game not displaying

Tags: javascript, html, css, background-image

In a simple HTML,CSS and JavaScript game, I replaced (in the CSS)

```
background-color:green;
```

with

```
background-image: url(flappybird.png);
```

and I also tried: (and with single quotations)

```
background-image: url("flappybird.png");
```

but the image is not being displayed on the page. I have tried adding the semi colon and also speech marks.

I also tried adding z-index=10000000 to character, but that didn't help.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong. I can confirm that the image is named correctly flappybird.png and is in the root folder.

```js
var character = document.getElementById("character");
var enemy = document.getElementById("enemy");



function jump(){
    if(character.classlist!="animate"){
    character.classList.add("animate");
    }
    setTimeout(function(){
        character.classList.remove("animate");
    },500);
    
}

//right movement

function right() {

  var leftVal =  parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(character).getPropertyValue("left"))
  character.style.left = (leftVal + 30) + "px";

}

//left movement

function left() {

  var leftVal =  parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(character).getPropertyValue("left"))
  character.style.left = (leftVal - 30) + "px";

}




var checkDead =setInterval(function(){
    var characterTop = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(character).getPropertyValue("top"));
    var enemyLeft = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(enemy).getPropertyValue("left"));
    //ADD VARIABLE TO FIND CHARACTER RIGHT -if it collides with enemy left, you are out
    //remove the condition that the enemy has to be in the first 30 pixels of the game (left side)
    var characterRight =parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(character).getPropertyValue("right"));
    
 
    
    if(
        characterTop==enemyLeft //have tried characterRight==enemyLeft didn't work
    )
    {
        enemy.style.animation="none"; //remove the animation
        enemy.style.display="none";
        alert("Game Over");
        
    } 
},10);


//left
addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 37) left()
})

//jump (up)
addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 38) {
    jump()
  }
})

//right
addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 39) {
    right()
  }
})
```

```css
*{
        padding:0;
        margin:22;
    }
    
    #game{
        width:500px;
        height:500px;
        border:4px solid #171918;
    }
    
    #character{
        width:30px;
        height:120px;
        /*background-color:green;*/
        background-image: url(flappybird.png);
        position:relative;
        top:320px;
        border-radius:20px;
        /*animation: jump 300ms */
        
    }
    
    /* new class called animate */
    .animate{
        animation: jump 500ms;
    }
    
    
    #enemy{
        width:60px;
        height:60px;
        background-color:red;
        border-radius:14px;
        position:relative;
        top:320px;
        le

ft:440px;
    animation: moveenemy 1s infinite linear;
    
}

@keyframes moveenemy{
    0%{left:440px;}
    50%{top:58px;}
    100%{left:0px; top:320x;}
}

@keyframes jump{
    0%{top:380px;}
    30%{top:50px;}
    50%{top:40px;}
    100%{top:380px;}
}



/* adding sky*/
#sky{
    width:500px;
    height:340px;
    background-color:skyblue;
    position:absolute;
    top:118px;
}

/* adding ground */
#ground{
    width:500px;
    height:170px;
    background-color:bisque;
    position:absolute;
    top:450px;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Game</h1>
   <div id="game">
        <div id="sky"></div>
       <div id="ground"></div>
        <div id="enemy"></div>
       <div id="character"></div>
   </div>
   
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

A comment below suggests the option to resize and add background-size: cover;
This works to some extent but does not solve the problem of getting the image to fit the specifications we want. Resizing the width and height here, doesn't resize - it just uncovers or covers the image.

If I was to use an image, it should also resize, and I note the width and height don't work as expected in this situation. Could that also be addressed in any answers.

The **below code** thus uncovers the image if I adjust the width and height, but does not resize correctly, which I cannot figure out.

```
#character{
    width:60px;
    height:50px;
    /*background-color:green;*/

    background-image: url(flappybird.png);
    position:relative;
    top:320px;
    background-size: cover;
    /*animation: jump 300ms */
```

Comment: I've already mentioned that in my question - that didn't work either - someone just deleted my comment and that I had tried that. I also used speech marks and that didn't work either

Comment: Add `background-size: cover;` to `#character `. Does this fix it? Since your declaration is correct (of the url)

Comment: Thanks Lars, but nope - didn't fix it....but oddly a part of the image is poking out. hmm

Comment: I also tried z-index=10000000 - but that didn't seem to work

Comment: @LarsFlieger - your suggestion causes a quarter of the image to show and peek out. If you correct this, could you also provide an explanation as to why the original didn't work and why z-index didn't work - in the HTML this is in the right position (foreground) so why has it gone to the background? Useful to understand what's going on behind the scenes.

Comment: and another question here if you're interested :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66061515/if-statement-in-javascript-game-not-working-as-desired-to-allow-for-collision-de?noredirect=1#comment116798741_66061515

Comment: @LarsFlieger - notably background-size:cover; also covers everything - including the other block in the game (the red block) - so that wouldn't work in that context anyway.

Comment: Okay but the issue is not the url. It the position / size of the background image. :) Work on that :)

Comment: ah......lightbulb. Thank you!

Comment: happy to accept answer if you put it in as an answer. Also do have a look at the other question if possible! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66061515/if-statement-in-javascript-game-not-working-as-desired-to-allow-for-collision-de?noredirect=1#comment116798741_66061515

Comment: Would still like an answer - as it is not obvious how to size it to the dimensions we want. We can only "uncover" it by playing with the width and height....and this does not necessarily leave us with the image size we want, if that makes sense. For instance, a larger image would just be cut off...but what if I wanted it resized to specified dimensions. I have updated my answer to reflect this - thank you :)(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is [this](https://codepen.io/ePresas/pen/zYorLbL) what you want to achieve? I added a little border to show the width problem solved.

```
#character {
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
  background: url("https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fatomix.vg%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2014%2F05%2FFlappy-Bird.png&f=1&nofb=1")
    center no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  border-radius: 20px;
  /*animation: jump 300ms */
}
```

**Update**:

The `background-size: contain;`rule tells the background to adjust its size to the container, without stretching it, your can read more info about the values of this rule [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size). If the container is bigger than the img, it might repeat, so it's wise to control it with `background-repeat: no-repeat;`, or use the shorthand version of `background: <url> <position> <repeat>;` more on that [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background).

About the change of the top from `px` to `%` it was purely experimental while trying to resolve your question. You can add your original value.

Comment: this is - but @epresas could you please provide an explanation - see my question and the specifics that I am asking - the explanations are important if that's okay

Comment: There is also this related question if you're interested https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66061515/if-statement-in-javascript-game-not-working-as-desired-to-allow-for-collision-de?noredirect=1#comment116798741_66061515

Comment: For instance, what is top:50%  and background-size:contain achieving. How does it solve the problem I was describing re the width and height.

Comment: I updated the answer to explain the changes I made. I'm still trying to improve in contributing in stack overflow, so thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Thanks - are you saying top can be removed and it will make no difference?

Comment: Yes, it was purely experimental, before you had an initial value in pixels, to initialize the character in a position I assume. Either way is fine. If you remove it, it would reposition to  its original flow position.